# What is the literal meaning of displacement current?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, terminology, displacement

I think I know what the [displacement current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_current) is.
But I don't know why they use the word "displacement" exactly.
What is the literal meaning of "displacement" of the displacement current?
Why don't they call it "electric flux variation current"?

Comment: We are simply stuck with the silly name that Maxwell chose for it. It is not at all a current so your choice is not very nice either.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the wikipedia article: at the time Maxwell named it that way the name seemed fitting to him.

When the physics community adopted Maxwell's theory of electromagnetism (which actually took decades) all of the names that were introduced by Maxwell were adopted. Presumably: at the time there was no need to rename things.

In general, it rarely happens, if ever, that if over time it turns out that the name of some concept is is awkward, that the name is changed. Presumably that is perceived as more hassle than it is worth.

A particularly striking example is the name 'Gauge theory'. The ideas that turned into the general framework referred to as 'Gauge theory' had a predecessor, formulated by Hermann Weyl, which involved scaling of physical size. Hermann Weyl named that scaling-of-size idea after the gauge blocks used by machinists for measuring. Later the idea of size scaling was abandoned and replaced with change of phase. But at that point the name 'Gauge theory' was already so widespread that using another name for the new development would actually be more confusing than retaining the existing name. So it's still referred to as 'Gauge theory' even though that name doesn't make sense.

Returning to the name 'displacement current'. Displacement current has the property that a changing displacement current induces a magnetic field. That is: there is a very close connection with the concept of current.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the name is historical. Maxwell used this name in the first volume of his Treatise to indicate what we presently call the [electric displacement field or electric induction field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_displacement_field) and indicate with the vector ${\bf D} $. The name was because, in a dielectric material, ${\bf D} $ contains information about the electric dipole moment density in the material.

Typically, a dipole can be varied by a relative *displacement* of positive and negative charges.

Once the ${\bf D} $ field was named displacement field, the presence in the Maxwell equations of a term $\frac{\partial{{\bf D}}}{\partial{t}}$ added to the electric current density ${\bf j}$, made natural to call it *displacement current density*.

Presently, we look at these names as a historical heritage. In particular, we keep these names even in the case of the equation in the vacuum, where there is no displacement at all, after the concept of a material ether disappeared.

Comment: According to your explanation, it looks like that the first use of "displacement"  is "displacement of positive and negative charges". If then, does initial "displacement" mean that "positive charges and negative charges are not in the same place (or same point)"?

Comment: @superkappy More than my explanation is the content of the first part of Maxwell's Treatise (in particular section 75). The meaning of electric displacement was precisely an increase in the distance between positive and negative charges. The vector field we presently call displacement field or electric induction field, denoted by the vector $\bf{D}$ was called by Maxwell "Induction" and denoted by $R$, but was explicitly introduced ad depending on the electric displacement, i.e. what today we would call an increase of the dipole moment..